# Preprocessor ifdef in file.h

Tags: c++, qt

I developed a program with qt, c ++ on Visual Express 2010 and I use two versions of qwt (qwt5 and qwt6)

in the .h file of my class I added a test on the includes files

I also did a test for the statements slots (because the type of parameters changes between the version qwt5 and qwt6)

here's the code in .h :

```
#ifdef QWT6
    void leftPlotPickerSelected ( const QPointF& ); //qwt6
#else
    void leftPlotPickerSelected ( const QwtDoublePoint & ); // qwt5
#endif
```

and in the .cpp file, I also added the test as follows:

```
#ifdef QWT6
connect ( m_pPlotPickerLeft, SIGNAL ( selected ( const QPointF&) ),SLOT ( leftPlotPickerSelected ( const QPointF&))  ); //qwt6
#else
connect ( m_pPlotPickerLeft, SIGNAL ( selected ( const QwtDoublePoint & ) ), SLOT ( leftPlotPickerSelected ( const QwtDoublePoint & ) ) ); //qwt5
#endif
```

when I run my program by debugging, the connection to each slot does not work, and showing me a warning in output:

```
Warning: Object::connect: No such slot      classeA::leftPlotPickerSelected ( const QPointF&)
Warning: Object::connect:  (receiver name: 'classeABase')
```

But when I commented the #endif at the statement of slots in the .h file, the connection works well,

I do not know why the test #endif in .h file blocks connections slots ?

Can you help me please . Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you run qmake before building the project?

Comment: No ,but i have generated 2 versions of my program ( 32bit and 64bit): for 64bit it work very well without problem , but the issue in 32bit version.Have you an idea please?thank you for your response.

Comment: I use cmake for building the project.

Comment: Please provide some more context. I take it the code in the header is part of a `slots` section? You've not shown that. Also, you've not told us whether the macro `QWT6` is defined or not when you build the code which fails to connect. Also, are you passing the macro to `moc` as well?

Comment: thank you Angew for your response , i have added the macro to moc and it works verry wel , thank you very much